# Custom validation attribute is not working for button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a function for doing on validations on textbox entered value based on selection in drop downlist .. ..suppose If the dropdownlist  selected item is **amount** then the entered value in textbox must be in between  10 t0 20 like this i have got two more validations.. for that purpose, I have got one textbox and one dropdwonlist and one button in my view

when i enter value in textbox as 30 and select the drop downlist item as "Amount" and then click on the submit button, the view is not showing any error message and ( if i left textbox as empty and then press submit button its should show error msg but its not showing)  (I have written Custom functions for validating these ones  on server side) 
I have put a breakpoint at a postValues method but its not hitting ...

for that I have done like this (controller part)

```
  public class CrossFieldsTxtboxesController : Controller
  {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var itemsforDropdown = new List<SelectListItem> {             
                new SelectListItem{ Text = "Amount" , Value = "Amount"},
                new SelectListItem{Text= "Pound", Value ="Pound"},
                new SelectListItem {Text ="Percent", Value ="percent"}            
            };
            ViewData["Listitems"] = itemsforDropdown;
            return View("DdlCrossFields");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostValues(CrossFieldValidation model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("DdlCrossFields");                
            }            
        }    
    }
```

and this is my view part

```
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.CrossFieldValidation
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DdlCrossFields";
}    
<h2>DdlCrossFields</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    <div class ="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TxtCrossField)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.TxtCrossField)
    </div>
    @Html.DropDownList("Listitems",ViewData["Listitems"] as SelectList)
    <input id="PostValues" type="Submit" value="PostValues" />
}
```

and this is my model part

```
public class CrossFieldValidation
{        
    public string DDlList1
    { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity is required")]
    [Display(Name= "Quantity:")]
    [ValueMustbeInRange]
    [NumericAttributes] 
    public string TxtCrossField
    { get; set; }
}
```

would any one have any idea why its not working for button click , any suggestions also would be grateful
many thanks..

Comment: The question is presently tagged with MVC3 and MVC4; which are you actually using?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012...and mvc 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any place where you specify an action that should handle POST request (`PostValues` in your case). You can use an overload of `Html.BeginForm` and specify POST action name explicitly:

```
Html.BeginForm("PostValues", "CrossFieldsTxtboxes")
```

If I'm right, your POST requests go to `Index` action and therefore `ModelState.IsValid` is not checked there.

You can use client side validation using jQuery Unobtrusive validation plugin. Please check if you have the following keys in your `web.config` file:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

But note that custom validation attributes require additional JavaScript code to work on client.

Comment: I have checked in web config  file every thing is okk

Comment: thanks I am getting this error "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Listitems'."  at this line    @Html.DropDownList("Listitems",ViewData["Listitems"] as SelectList).. would you pls help on this ....

Comment: Is it after you submitting a form to `PostValues`? You need to initialize `ViewData["ListItems"]` in `PostValues` method as well, just refactor creating list items in a separate method and use it in `Index` and `PostValues`

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where you are actually calling the method when you do the post - do you have a javscript click handler?

You need to have the method and controller you want to go to in your `Html.BeginForm()` or you can have something like the below in your view:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Post Values", "PostValues", "CrossFieldsTxtboxesController", null, new { @class = "postValuesButton", onclick = "return false;" })
```